# How to use selenium webdriver to download DNA sequence from NCBI?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have started learning selenium in Python and, basically, I am a Bioinformatics student. I want to download a DNA sequence data in "fasta" format from the link:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_044604.1?report=fasta

I am aware of the fact that downloading .fasta sequence is possible by Biopython. I would like to try with selenium. Following is the code I've written.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

url=input("Enter the URL: ")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\python\webdriver_chrome\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)

elements=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[./div[starts-with(@id,'viewer')]]//pre")

file=open(r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\seleniumtext1.text", "a+")

file.write(str(elements.text))

file.close()
```

[You may look at the html structure I want to scrape, here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzzYk.png)

But I am not able to download the entire sequence.
I have attached the actual sequence downloaded via "Biopython" and the one via "selenium" at: https://mega.nz/folder/tV0BESjY#iQIbdeKPOxS78bvhtcC1BQ

Is there any correction needed at the "XPATH"?
Please educate me on this.

Comment: The URL is "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_044604.1?report=fasta"

Answer (score 0):

The page takes a while to render so you will need to include a waiting method.  In my tests 30 seconds wasn't even enough time to fully render the entire sequence.

Additionally your xpath expression is incorrect.

I tested this example and it worked for me.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url=input("Enter the URL: ")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\python\webdriver_chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
elements=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='viewercontent1']//pre")
with open(r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\seleniumtext1.txt", "a+") as ofile:
    for element in elements:
        ofile.write(element.text)
```